# Bad Request - This combination of host and port requires TLS. with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, ssl

I'm newbie with Spring Boot.

I'm trying to make a https call to a service, I have a Privake key to secure connection.

I hit:

```
http://localhost:8081/points/12345/search
```

I tried with https:// but I get from Postman:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://localhost:8081/points/12345/search.
```

From the moment I wrote

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:KeyStore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=test
```

in `application.properties`, I get the error message:

Bad Request - This combination of host and port requires TLS

I have deleted all my code in my controller, I just let the endpoint so that I can invoke it.

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/points/{point}/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public PointsType getPoint(@PathVariable(value = "point") String point) {
        System.out.println("hi"); // Never printed
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is the file application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=sge
server.port=8081
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:KeyStore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=test
server.ssl.key-alias=homologation-staging
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:TrustStore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=test
server.ssl.client-auth=need
security.require-ssl=true
server.tomcat.remote_ip_header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol_header=x-forwarded-proto
```

What should I do ?

Comment: You enabled ssl, so you should use `https://localhost:8081/....` and not `http`.

Comment: I already tried to deploy it with a domain name in https, but it gave the same result.

Comment: Where do I say you need to deploy? Apparently you are accessing it through `http` and not `https` at least that is what the error is telling you.

Comment: I tried with https:// but I get: Could not get any response from postman. I put it in my question.

Comment: Check your server log to see what went wrong.

Comment: Ok, instead of running directly from VSCode config, I ran it with ./gradlew bootRun and could bypass the error. Please put it as an answer ! Thanks

Comment: @Juliatzin Del Toro - I used a self-signed certificate in my developer machine. Hence the browser warns the certificate error when accessing via https:// and right port# I configured in server.xml. I accepted the risk of using the self signed certificate. You might need to add such certificate error exceptions in postman tool.

Comment: have you been able to solve this? without weird suggestions?

Comment: @NumanKaraaslan Yes, the issue was I was using a server certificate instead of using a client certificate, so, this is the message when you have an issue with your https connections I guess.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I used `https://` at the beginning instead of `http://`, it worked for me.

Comment: Although some solutions might work for certain use cases they may not for others. Thus please give more context to the reason why your solution may or may not work. Also you could use the comment option for suggesting possible ideas rather than giving them as answers.

Comment: Hi, thank you for suggestions. I guess I had to get 50 reputation before making comments (except for answering here), but I'll try to expand and explain my answer when I'm available.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue myself and searched for days for an answer. Most responses talk about using https instead of http but that wasn't required for my testing on localhost. I got my much needed resolution from Shubham's options, which was to set  server.ssl.enabled in application.properties file to false.

Answer (score 3):

I got this message because I was using wrong certificate.

I misunderstood Client certificate and Server certificate.

In my case, I installed my certificate on the server, for my domain, but what I needed to do instead is to use it to make the request, as a client certificate.

you can check it how to do it here.

[Client Certificate Authentication with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177317/client-certificate-authentication-with-spring-boot)

So this message is basically saying: "Hey, your SSL request is not OK", I can't find the cert file, or your cert file is not the good one, as @SerdarAtalay says, it can also significate that you didn't use `https://` prefix, etc.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

We can fix this by either of below listed solutions.

1. Use HTTPS  instead of HTTP
2. Disable TLS encryption from POSTMAN setting and use HTTP
3. Check application properties server.ssl.enabled= true- HTTPS , false-HTTP
4. Add correct authorization credential like username and password in POSTMAN
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sejdB.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGOj9.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sejdB.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPvKC.png)

Answer (score 1):

Error:
**Bad Request This combination of host and port requires TLS.**

*If you are using apache Load balancer to connect your App node.
Please check application.conf file under /etc/httpd/conf.d/ and add below entry if not added.*

SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

Restart httpd service and check.

Comment: people who are using tomcat, there will be no httpd in the etc folder in linux

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when working on a **Java Project** in **Debian 10** with **Tomcat** as the application server.

The issue was that the application already had **https** defined as it's default protocol while I was using **http** to call the application in the browser.

I however tried using the **https** protocol in the browser but it didn't connect throwing the error:

> Secure Connection Failed

> An error occurred during a connection to 34.72.188.50:8009. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

> Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
> Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

**Here's how I solved it**:

I first had to create a **keystore** file for the application, more like a self-signed certificate for the **https** protocol:

```
sudo keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -keystore /usr/share/tomcat.keystore
```

**Note**: You need to have Java installed on the server to be able to do this. Java can be installed using `sudo apt install default-jdk`.

Next, I added a **https** Tomcat server connector for the application in the Tomcat server configuration file (`/opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml`):

```
sudo nano /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml
```

Add the following to the configuration of the application. Notice that the **keystore** file location and password are specified. Also a port for the **https** protocol is defined, which is different from the port for the **http** protocol:

```xml
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200" scheme="https"
           secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="/usr/share/tomcat.keystore"
           keystorePass="my-password"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           compression="force"
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css"/>
```

So the full server configuration for the application looked liked this in the **Tomcat** server configuration file (`/opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml`):

```xml
<Service name="my-application">
  <Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
             port="8443" maxThreads="200" scheme="https"
             secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
             keystoreFile="/usr/share/tomcat.keystore"
             keystorePass="my-password"
             clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
             URIEncoding="UTF-8"
             compression="force"
             compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css"/>
```

```xml
  <Connector port="8009" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
             connectionTimeout="20000"
             redirectPort="8443" />

  <Engine name="my-application" defaultHost="localhost">
     <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
    </Realm>

    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
          unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
             prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
             pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

    </Host>
  </Engine>
</Service>
```

This time when I tried accessing the application from the browser using:

```
https://my-server-ip-address:https-port
```

In my case it was:

```
https:35.123.45.6:8443
```

it worked fine. Although, I had to accept a warning which added a security exception for the website, since the certificate used is a self-signed one.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but if you're using Spring Boot v2, the solution is much simpler:

1. Acknowledge that `server.port` will change from HTTP to HTTPS if you add SSL config fields in `application.properties`.
2. [Optional] Add `.properties` configuration fields:

   ```
   # Original port configuration for HTTP, now being used for HTTPS
   server.port=${PORT:8443}

   # Our own custom field (this isn't defined by Spring)
   server.http.port=${HTTP_PORT:8080}

   # Spring's SSL configs
   server.ssl.key-store=${SSL_KEY_FILE:classpath:keystore.p12}
   server.ssl.key-store-password=${SSL_PASSWORD:password}
   server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
   server.ssl.keyAlias=tomcat
   ```
3. Add a new `@Configuration` class (or just add the new method below to an existing one) to create a new Tomcat connector to support a second port:

   ```java
   @Configuration
   public class ApplicationConfig {
       @Value("${server.http.port}")
       private int SERVER_HTTP_PORT;

       @Bean
       public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
           Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
           connector.setPort(SERVER_HTTP_PORT);

           TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
           tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);

           return tomcat;
       }
   }
   ```

Credit to the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896234/how-set-up-spring-boot-to-run-https-http-ports/52648698#52648698), I'm just forwarding the information along.