# What is the best Security Implementation for WebApi and Web Applications

Tags: security, authentication, webapi

I'm trying to create a web application that uses a Web API to perform database operations. I've created a project at work that uses Windows Authentication on the API Level. Since this is an intranet web application I don't need to implement a login mechanism on the web application. However, this project I'm working on can be private or public web application and I would like to implement a login mechanism but I would like to be able to specify what type of security to use i.e. LDAP, generic username/password, Google, Facebook, etc.

The question is, what is the best strategy to implement security on both Web Application and Web Api. For Web Api, I could probably implement some soft of token mechanism like other Apis. But not sure if there are other ways.

Is Sign-in option like Google, Facebook, etc done on the Front-end side? or can I Implement it on the WebApi side?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice on this case,

- Web Application: [client certificate authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177317/client-certificate-authentication-with-spring-boot) or username/password
- Web API: JWT

or if the target company uses G suits with the company domain, Google will be okay.
You can set a filter using domain name of the email address.

Comment: Thanks rymuff. I'm just curious. When we started using JIRA from Atlassian, it required username and password (LDAP) now it's using DUO. I'm just wondering how to implement similar architecture.