Configuring ssl in springboot3
I am trying to configure SSL in my springboot3 app.  I referred to spring documentation mentioned here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/ssl.html#:~:text=to%20lowercase.-,Configuring%20SSL%20With%20PEM%2Dencoded%20Certificates,-Configuration%20properties%20with. I have my .crt and .key in my container  and configured the .crt and .key in my application.yaml. I had both added to server. ssl and spring.ssl. (though I understand that one might be enough). I receive the error "Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'".

Do I just need changes in application.yaml to make my springboot3 work in SSL?
Do I need to convert .crt and .key  to any other format? or can Springboot3 work with that fine?
How can I fix my errors? I understand that it is related to SSL configuration. I tried this org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop' and Failed to start 'webServerStartStop' spring boot app and it didnt help. And fyi - I am trying to consume the.crt and .key during run time as they reside inside my container in eks cluster which I read during app start up.

server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    trust-store: mycert
    trust-store-password: xxx
    trust-store-type: JKS
    enabled: true
    bundle:
      pem:
        mybundle:
          jks:
            certificate: /container-path for/cert.crt
            private-key: /container=path-for/cert.key

spring:
  ssl:
    bundle:
      pem:
        mybundle:
          keystore:
            certificate: /container-path for/cert.crt
            private-key: /container=path-for/cert.key

you can see more detailed log and errors below
Starting Application v1.3.2 using Java 17.0.13 with PID 1 
INFO 1 ---com.Application              : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
INFO 1 ---o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Fetching config from server at : http://myservice
INFO 1 ---o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Located environment: name=config, profiles=[default], label=null, version=null, state=null
INFO 1 ---o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Fetching config from server at : http://my-config-service/
INFO 1 ---o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Located environment: name=config, profiles=[dev], label=null, version=null, state=null
INFO 1 ---.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
INFO 1 ---.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 16 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
INFO 1 ---o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=12345-1234-1234-a373-91234567
DEBUG 1 ---.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : Code archive: /my-services.jar
DEBUG 1 ---.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : Code archive: /my-services.jar
DEBUG 1 ---.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : None of the document roots [src/main/webapp, public, static] point to a directory and will be ignored.
INFO 1 ---o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8443 (https)
INFO 1 ---o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
INFO 1 ---o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.26]
INFO 1 ---o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
INFO 1 ---w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 13694 ms
INFO 1 ---i.m.datadog.DatadogMeterRegistry         : An application key must be configured in order for unit information to be sent to Datadog.
INFO 1 ---i.m.c.instrument.push.PushMeterRegistry  : publishing metrics for DatadogMeterRegistry every 1m
INFO 1 ---f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static java.lang.String com.ConnectionData.encryptionKey
DEBUG 1 ---o.s.w.f.ServerHttpObservationFilter      : Filter 'webMvcObservationFilter' configured for use
INFO 1 ---com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
INFO 1 ---com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:a9eab013-c418-4f14-94e6-07da7912a7d2 user=SA
INFO 1 ---com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
INFO 1 ---o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
INFO 1 ---org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.5.2.Final
INFO 1 ---o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
INFO 1 ---o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
INFO 1 ---o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
INFO 1 ---j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
WARN 1 ---JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
DEBUG 1 ---s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 17 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
DEBUG 1 ---o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
INFO 1 ---o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint beneath base path '/actuator'
INFO 1 ---o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@71dd4624, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2347b7af, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@5d7f1e59, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@734fbae3, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@2864f887, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@36b53f08, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@59e082f8, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@2475fba3, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3a861417, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@16ac4d3d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4b07cad0, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6f07d414, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@7493d937]
DEBUG 1 ---s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
DEBUG 1 ---.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
WARN 1 ---ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: **Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'**
INFO 1 ---j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
INFO 1 ---com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
INFO 1 ---com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
INFO 1 ---.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
51.261Z ERROR 1 ---o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: **Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'**
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:291) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar!/:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:471) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar!/:6.1.8]
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:260) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar!/:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:205) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar!/:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:981) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar!/:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar!/:6.1.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar!/:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar!/:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar!/:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar!/:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar!/:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar!/:3.3.0]
        
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[my-services.jar:1.3.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[my-services.jar:1.3.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[my-services.jar:1.3.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[my-services.jar:1.3.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:251) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar!/:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:44) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar!/:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:288) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar!/:6.1.8]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:222) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar!/:3.3.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:236) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar!/:3.3.0]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1061) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:114) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:70) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1304) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:643) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1058) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:386) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:684) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:221) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.security.KeyStoreUtil.load(KeyStoreUtil.java:69) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:254) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:308) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:268) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:112) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.26.jar!/:na]
        ... 33 common frames omitted


I hate when people do this to me, but here I go.  Sorry.  Why are you wanting to create a web server?  I ask, because the Apache/Tomcat handles SSL unless your really want to use app2app cert authentication.   If that is the case, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177317/client-certificate-authentication-with-spring-boot

I have my specific certificates which I want to use to configure ssl for my app. I get inside the container and I see the .crt and .key files there.

ingress or egress?

I was able to solve the problem. Sharing for others.
1. Do I just need changes in application.yaml to make my springboot3 work in SSL?
Yes. Springboot3 offers SSL bundle which can be used.
2. Do I need to convert .crt and .key to any other format? or can Springboot3 work with that fine?
Not required. In Springboot3, you can directly consume .crt and .key files
3. How can I fix my errors? I understand that it is related to SSL configuration. I tried this org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop' and Failed to start 'webServerStartStop' spring boot app and it didnt help. And fyi - I am trying to consume the.crt and .key during run time as they reside inside my container in eks cluster which I read during app start up.
you just need below changes in your application.yml file and can consume .crt and .key directly from your local or from your container. In my case, I added the port as 8443 in my application yaml but my app was exposed in 8083. I fixed that too.
server:
  port: 8083 
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    bundle: mybundle
    enabled-protocols: TLSv1.3

spring:
  ssl:
    bundle:
      pem:
        mybundle:
          keystore:
            certificate: /path/to/cert.crt
            private-key: /path/to/cert.key
      jks:
        client:
          trust-store:
            location: classpath:trust.jks
            password: <truststore password> 
            type: jks


Client Certificate Authentication with Spring Boot
https://medium.com/geekculture/authentication-using-certificates-7e2cfaacd18b
# Define a custom port instead of the default 8080
server.port=8443

# Tell Spring Security (if used) to require requests over HTTPS
security.require-ssl=true

# The format used for the keystore 
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password= {your password here}
# The alias mapped to the certificate
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat

